# Exceptions handling in global.asax on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config

I have an ASP.NET application and want to process exceptions by `Application_Error` method in `Global.asax`.

In config I use `customError="Off"` setting.

All works fine on local or remote server. `Application_Error` method executes and redirects to custom error pages.

But after I deploy app in Azure, I always get default error pages (YSOD). I think, Application_Error handler in Global.asax not fires.I haven't any ideas why. Maybe Azure has special setting for choose fire this handler or not.
Can anyone explain this?

If I set `customError="RemoteOnly"` setting and add default redirect page, all works.
But I have business logic in my handler, therefore I want to use `Application_Error` method.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? Why do you use customError off in web config? Do you want to see the error? You dont want to see the error? You want to see the custom page?

Comment: I think i was mistaken. I use mode On, instead of Off (change question), user must see exception without detailed info. I want to see custom error pages, but with specific logic. For this I use Application_Error handler.

Comment: One more question, are you using MVC Framework? If so have you attempted using the filters for error handling instead of global.asax

Comment: I use mixed web app with MVC and old ASP NET, so I must use global.asax. After double check my config, I use customErrors in Off mode (for handle exceptions in global.asax method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I finally resolve my problem. ASP NET works fine and handle exceptions, but I have app setting in web config for enable/disable custom error pages. This setting processed in `Application_Error` method. And Azure has app setting too, and they override settings from web config.

For more info about Azure app settings: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2015/10/09/using-app-settings-in-azure-web-apps.aspx